# NullInjectorError on a interceptor Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor, angular16

I'm creating a new interceptor on an Angular 16 project, and when trying to inject MatSnackBar, I'm getting the following error:

> NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar!

I need to open a snackbar when the API returns an error code, and I create a snackbar service to make it easier to call it, but trying to use the service or the MatSnackBar itself, I'm getting the same error.

Interceptor  code:

```
export const requisicaoErrosInterceptor = (
    req: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandlerFn
): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> => {
    try {
        let matsnack = inject(MatSnackBar);
        //let snackBarService = inject(SnackBarService);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return next(req).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            return event;
        }),
        catchError((err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                let mensagem = '';

                if (err.status === 0) {
                    mensagem = 'mensagem-problemas-conexao';
                }

                return throwError(() => err);
            }
        })
    );
};
```

My provider:

```
import {
    HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    provideHttpClient,
    withInterceptors,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { EnvironmentProviders, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { requisicaoErrosInterceptor } from './interceptors/requisicao.erros.interceptor';
import { requisicaoInterceptor } from './interceptors/requisicao.interceptor';

export const provideAplicacao = (): Array<Provider | EnvironmentProviders> => {
    return [
        provideHttpClient(
            withInterceptors([requisicaoErrosInterceptor])
        ),
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useValue: () => {},
            multi: true,
        },
    ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Class-based Interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class RequisicaoErrosInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}
    
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        // Your interceptor logic here...
    }
}
```

then provide it in your providers arra

```
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: RequisicaoErrosInterceptor,
    multi: true
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting DI error (NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken). 

I thinks is same problem of null injection, because DI error happens before when I'm trying to inject a service with MatSnackBar on constructor.

Comment: @MarcosV.RezendeS. have you solved it? I also got problems with injecting service in interceptor

Comment: @Mateusz Yes, I imported the MatSnackBarModule before the declaration of my interceptor and it worked fine. In my case the interceptor was declare on app.config.ts